# How to programmatically show MKUserLocation annotation view?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I would like to select the `MKUserLocation` of the current user location programmatically as soon as the `MKMapView` shows.

I have tried by doing so:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didAddAnnotationViews views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
    for annotation in views {
        if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
            mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation.annotation!, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are checking if MKAnnotationView is of type MKUserLocation. Instead you should check if MKAnnotationView's annotation is MKUserLocation.

```
views.forEach() { view in
    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation {
        mapView.selectAnnotation(view.annotation!, animated: true)
    }
}
```